# Снять метку со всех RadioButton

Tags: delphi, vcl

На форме расположено множество RadioButton переключателей. Задача состоит в том, чтобы по кнопке сбросить им всем состояние в `Checked = False`. Как решить задачу, не обращаясь к объекту каждого переключателя?

Comment: +1. И все же это может быть не совсем верно - смысл радиобаттонов как раз в том, чтобы всегда была выбрана какая-либо опция.

Comment: @Kromster, на самом деле, проблема немножко другая. Если я располагаю RadioButtons на разных GroupBox\Panel то при они получаются независимыми друг от друга. А мне нужно, чтобы включенным был только выбранный переключатель. Приходится выдумывать велосипеды в виде отжимания остальных)))

Comment: Тогда ок. Но комментарий я оставлю, чтобы предостеречь будущих читателей )

Answer (score 2):

Решил следующим образом (может кому пригодится)

```
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
  begin
    if (Components[i] is TRadioButton) then
    begin
      (Components[i] as TRadioButton).Checked := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: А зачем вам TWinControl и его CanFocus?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci и действительно, спасибо)

Comment: Кстати, если RadioButton **очень** много, то можно сделать оптимальнее НМВ: назначить каждому обработчик OnClick() и в нём делать: `FSelectedRB.Checked := False; FSelectedRB := Sender`, где `FSelectedRB` - это приватное поле формы, типа TRadioButton (не компонент на форме!). Ну и не забыть при создании формы назначить ему TRadioButton по-умолчанию, чтобы не получить AV. Это, к тому же, позволит иметь на этой форме несколько разных групп TRadioButton.